# How to make display in search bar text?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I create searchBar in my app. I used NSPredicte but doesn't work. 
This is my: 
.m file: http://pastebin.com/CMsXpk4N
and .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface WordsViewController : UITableViewController <UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchControllerDelegate, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *finalResultArray;
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;

@end
```

Where I have mistakes in my searchBar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try change your NSPredicate in this way

```
NSArray *filterArray= [self.finalResultArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K contains[c] %@", @"expression", self.searchBar.text]];
```

`predicateWithFormat` will by himself apply `@"expression" key to each element of array, so you don't need to specify`self` in predicate format string.

Also, in predicate format string placeholder for key should be %K, not %@.

Comment: Does `-(void) searchBar:textDidChange:` called? Did you set delegate for searchBar? If not - add this to `-viewDidLoad` : `searchBar.delegate = self;`

Comment: @mechu911 Did you have any success?

Comment: @mechu911 You have always pay attention to warning Xcode give you. You get this  "Autosynthesized property 'searchBar' will use synthesized instance variable '_searchBar', not existing instance variable 'searchBar'" -this is the first. Second, you have set wrong outlet connections from your storyboard. Here is fixed project http://www.ex.ua/719057552266

Comment: @mechu911 You can, for example, insert first row that will contain text you want to display